# How to use one scene's camera in another scene?

Tags: unity, camera, scene

I have two scenes in my game: one is the menu scene with the UI and the other is the scene where all my game items are.

Right now my UI looks too plain, so what I want is to display my actual game scene in its background. I have plans to make the camera view move between two points so as to have an animated scene running.

I can think of one way to do this, which will be to duplicate the game scene and bring it to the UI scene but it would be clunky. Can I use other scene's camera to display its content in another scene?

Comment: Did you try? It seems what your asking would be quicker to test than to actually post a question about.

Comment: i can do it the way as i described in the question but that would be too impractical since it would waste too much space. i am asking about using a single camera for both the scenes. and no i cant try it if i dont know how to do it.

Comment: If you don't wish to bring the UI across, *what are you actually trying to do?*

Answer (score 1):

In Unity 5 you can embed multiple scenes in one scene by dragging them from the projects folder into your scene. You can then choose to render multiple cameras at the same time.

For Unity 4 you probably want to either set the level as a prefab if that fits your game structure or just build the main menu into the actual level, which may improve scene transitions.